# Select From Database With Name Containing Special Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a few databaseswith names such as **029jdfj-jh73jsd-hsdjhd7** and **uew723-73823n-783nd**. When I try to run a select statement, the following error is thrown:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '029jdfj'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'uew723'.
```

How can I select from these databases?

The select statement:

```
select Name from 029jdfj-jh73jsd-hsdjhd7.dbo.Names where Name like 'JWS Tech' or select Name from uew723-73823n-783nd.dbo.Names where Name like 'JWS Tech'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square brackets around your unorthodox names:

```
select Name from [029jdfj-jh73jsd-hsdjhd7].dbo.Names where Name like 'JWS Tech'
select Name from [uew723-73823n-783nd].dbo.Names where Name like 'JWS Tech'
```

More information on when and why you need to delimit your identifiers this way can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).

> Identifiers that do not comply with all the rules for identifiers must be delimited in a Transact-SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name 
from [029jdfj-jh73jsd-hsdjhd7].dbo.Names 
where Name like '%JWS Tech%' 
UNION
select Name
from [uew723-73823n-783nd].dbo.Names
where Name like '%JWS Tech%'
```

You should use `union` instead of `or` for combining 2 result sets.
Also use `%` when you look for patterns with `like`. Also, if your schema-name starts with a number, better use `[]` as @sstan said in his answer.